# Reporting Services not working with IE10 or Chrome on win 8

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, internet-explorer-10

Our 2008R2 SSRS implementation recently stopped working with IE10 and chrome on windows 8.  The headings will display and the data section is blank.  The export to excel function still allows for download of the report.  Running in compatibility mode will let the report display correctly. Has anyone else experienced this issue?  I could not find anything on MS site about the issue.  Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: I tried IE 10 with SSRS 2008R2 with Windows 7, and it is working fine. Do you know if this report is actually has any data in result set ?

Answer (score 2):

We've had problems with this before, more with Chrome than IE, but it could be the same issue.

Try having a look at this article and see if it fixes your issue, it worked for us:

[Report Doesn't Show](http://grumpydba.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/sql-2008-r2-report-doesnt-show-on.html)

One thing to note (that caught me out) is that you have to clear the cache of the browser on the client once you've made the change for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this metatag near the top of the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```